# Elasticsearc CORS despair

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, elasticsearch, cors

I installed ES5.4 in local environnment and I try to make a request to the API from my web browser with ajax request (using jQuery), and the CORS policy breaks it.

I read [ES HTTP documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) and some forums but I can't resolve my problem.

Here is my elasticsearch.yml http conf:

```
http.port: 9200
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length
http.cors.enabled: true
network-host: localhost
```

Here are my request params :

```
// simple query string 
var queryFilter = {
  "query": {
    "match":  {
      "id_opp":"OPP_4"
    }
  }
};

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:9200/_search",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: JSON.stringify(queryFilter),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data): {console.log(data)}
  }, 
  error: function(xhr){console.log(xhr)}
);
```

This is result from browser : Code POST 200 OK

In the browser network tool I get some objects in the result, it's good but my JavaScript code reads the ajax result as a fail:

> responseText:""
>   xhr.statusText:"error"
>   success: null

Could you help me to get success result in my ajax request?

Her is my response :

```
{
    "took": 33,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6,
        "max_score": 1.2438203,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "opportunites",
                "_type": "opportunity",
                "_id": "OPP_4-10_LT_26173_MCHE_002",
                "_score": 1.2438203,
                "_source": {
                    "@version": "1",
                    "id_opp": "OPP_4-10_LT_26173_MCHE_002",
                    "@timestamp": "2017-11-03T16:17:24.852Z",                    
                    "commune": "CHARPEY"
                }
            },
        }]
}
}
```

With Chrome after delete

> crossDomain: true,

and remove from .yml:

> http.cors.allow-methods: X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
>   Content-Length

I get this message :

> Failed to load http://localhost:9200/_search: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:90' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

This is corresponding Response Headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Warning: 299 Elasticsearch-5.6.3-1a2f265 "Content type
>   detection for rest requests is deprecated. Specify the content type
>   using the [Content-Type] header." "Tue, 07 Nov 2017 11:51:24 GMT"
>   content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 content-encoding: gzip
>   content-length: 6898

After insert contentType (already tested):

> contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",

I get this new error :

> Fail to load http://localhost:9200/_search: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin  'http://localhost:90' is therefore now allowed
>   access.

But my elasticsearch.yml contains :

> http.cors.allow-origin: "*" http.cors.enabled: true

Comment: `crossDomain: true` is not helping you. This will simulate a cross-domain request even when there isn't one. Read the jQuery ajax docs to understand what this option is. Really you'd only want it for testing / simulation purposes.

Comment: But anyway, if you got a 200 OK response, then it's not a CORS error. If there was a CORS error you wouldn't even get a response. (unless that 200 is the response to a pre-flight OPTIONS request and not your actual request?? In which case you should see a console error in most browsers.). Or perhaps the JSON in your response is not valid - can we see what your response looks like, please?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
yes it's my second idea : wrong return. i will paste it in few minutes :)

Comment: Just noticed that `http.cors.allow-methods: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length` makes no sense either. This is supposed to specify a list of HTTP methods (e.g GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS etc), not a list of other allowed headers. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html for the options available, and what the default is for this option.

Comment: Also your example has a syntax error: `success: function(data): {console.log(data)}
  }, ` needs to be `success: function(data) {console.log(data)
  }, `. Not sure if that reflects your real code or not.

Comment: I used Firefox in my virtual machine and after installed Chrome i have :

Access-Control-Allow-Origin error header is present on the requested resource. Origin "http:localhost:90" is therefore not allowed.

--> i tried without " http.cors.allow-methods: X-Requested-With..." -> anything change

--> Sorry in my code it's function (){} :)

Comment: the JSON is invalid. Paste it into https://jsonlint.com/ and it'll tell you where the problem is, but basically you have an extra `},` within the "hits" object which breaks the structure. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in Chrome seems to be a separate problem, because presumably then you don't get any response? It would seem that your server is not creating the response headers properly. You can check it in your browser's network tools to see what headers the server returned.

Comment: I just updated mi post with header response.

Comment: that's not a header, it's an error message (from the response, possibly?) telling you to include the content-type header in your request.

Comment: you'r right, it's Response Headers as i'd writing. i poste new error (never finish..)

Comment: `http.cors.allow-origin: "*" http.cors.enabled: true` is clearly not being respected, then. Check that you implemented that correctly as per the docs, and that it gets applied to OPTIONS requests (they need to be handled by elasticsearch if they aren't already, or you need to write something separate in your webserver config to allow that).

Comment: Thank you for your help, we resolved problem ! i post answer ;)

Comment: That's great, glad you were able to solve it. For future readers, your answer would be better if it explained what you had to change from your original code, and why. If you can do that, you'll get my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i resolved my problem ! Thank you ***ADyson*** for your support ;)

This is my http config (elasticsearch.yml)  :

```
http.port:9200
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-length, Accept
http.cors.enabled: true
```

This is my JavaScript code to request elasticsearch data :

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
// execute request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:9200/_search",
    data: JSON.stringify(queryFilter), // elastic filter
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```